# how to use `borrow::Borrow<…>` to accept anything that "borrows as" a trait?

Tags: generics, rust, borrow-checker

The [documentation for Rust's `core::convert::AsRef` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/convert/trait.AsRef.html) says:

> … `Borrow` has a blanket impl for any `T`, and can be used to accept either a reference or a value.

It then proceeds to [link to the `core::borrow::Borrow` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/borrow/trait.Borrow.html).

Indeed, that can be used to write generic code that can accept a parameter either by value or by reference – it represents the concept of *anything than can be borrowed as `&T`* and, since `T` can be borrowed as `&T`, this trivial example works perfectly:

```rs
fn report_by_either<T: Borrow<i32>>(either: T) {
    let x: i32 = *either.borrow();
    println!("x = {}", x);
}
⋮

report_by_either(5); // x = 5
report_by_either(&6); // x = 6
```

- [*playground*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9ae58e15e8d939085556e877ae25c9b)

What if one wishes to use `Borrow<…>` in more complicated scenarios — concretely: in generic code with generic constraints. Instead of representing the concept of *anything that borrows as `&T`*, how can one additionally express the constraint that `T` implements a trait?

A very simple example occurred to me, recently, when trying to work around the fact that [*Rust*'s ranges do not all implement `Copy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18045).

Consider this function which accepts anything that can provide [`RangeBounds<i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html):

```rs
fn report_by_value<R: RangeBounds<i32> + Debug>(value: R) {
    println!("range-bounds: `{:?}`", value);
}
```

This leads to a unsatisfyingly inconsistent experience for the caller:

1. If they pass *some* ranges, of the types that implement `Copy` (e.g. [`RangeTo`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/struct.RangeTo.html), [`RangeToInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/struct.RangeToInclusive.html), …), they'll be just fine.

   ```rs
   let range = ..100;
   report_by_value(range);
   report_by_value(range);
   report_by_value(range);
   ```
2. But, for other ranges (e.g. [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/struct.Range.html), [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html), …) they'd better call `clone()` or ownership of the range gets stolen:

   ```rs
   let range_from = 1..;
   report_by_value(range_from.clone());
   report_by_value(range_from.clone());

   report_by_value(range_from);
   report_by_value(range_from); // use of moved value: `range_from`
   ```

   - [*playground*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dcd0a541d8b7e51bc09c43d6fda89fa8)

One way to avoid this inconsistency is just to accept the range by reference:

```rs
fn report_by_reference<R: RangeBounds<i32> + Debug>(reference: &R) {
    println!("range-bounds: `{:?}`", reference);
}
```

But this *also* leads to clumsy code at the call-site:

```rs
report_by_reference(&(4..));
report_by_reference(&(..5));
report_by_reference(&(6..7));
```

It seemed like the obvious solution was to use [`borrow::Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/borrow/trait.Borrow.html):

```rs
fn report_by_either<R: RangeBounds<i32> + Debug, T: Borrow<R>>(either: T) {
    println!("range-bounds: `{:?}`", either.borrow());
}
```

Unfortunately, though, this prompted this question because type inference for the generic types does not work for this.

- Both of the following calls yield an error: "*cannot infer type of the type parameter `R` declared on the function `report_by_either`*":

  ```rs
  report_by_either(5..); // cannot infer type of the type parameter `R` declared on the function `report_by_either`
  report_by_either(&(6..)); // cannot infer type of the type parameter `R` declared on the function `report_by_either`
  ```
- These *turbo-fish*-blighted lines do work:

  ```rs
  report_by_either::<RangeFrom<i32>, _>(7..);
  report_by_either::<RangeFrom<i32>, _>(&(8..));
  ```
- [*playground*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=50416b54cc3f45091024e40c1d952474)

In this particularly scenario, I do not want my users to have to understand or even be aware of the reasons [why the range-types don't implement `Copy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18045) or the [inconsistencies that mean that not all of them don't](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/90190). I want my users to be able to pass me anything that gives `RangeBounds<…>`. That said, accepting only range-bounds by reference is not a disasterous compromise in my API in this case – `report_by_reference(&(6..7))` is clunky but tolerable.

More generally, however, I think that the concept of *anything that borrows as a trait* is certainly a common want.

How should I achieve it?

Comment: `Borrow` is a little bit tricky, but you can try `AsRef` instead.

Comment: There is no blanket implementation of `AsRef` for all types. In fact, the [documentation for `core::convert::AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/convert/trait.AsRef.html) specifically directs the reader towards `Borrow` for this very reason.

Comment: If you don't want to take ownership of the ranges, you shouldn't. Accept them by reference. It's fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty much out of luck here; you have two traits of indirection between `6..7` and your `&i32` and the compiler cannot deduce the intermediate type. For example, I can create a type that satisfies the constraints that *could* be an intermediate type:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Gobbledygook;

impl RangeBounds<i32> for Gobbledygook {
    fn start_bound(&self) -> Bound<&i32> { todo!() }
    fn end_bound(&self) -> Bound<&i32> { todo!() }
}

impl Borrow<Gobbledygook> for Range<i32> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &Gobbledygook { todo!() }
}

fn report_by_either<R: RangeBounds<i32> + Debug, T: Borrow<R>>(either: T) {
    println!("range-bounds: `{:?}`", either.borrow());
}

fn main() {
    report_by_either::<Gobbledygook, _>(0..7);
}
```

If the explicit type parameter were allowed to be omitted, which implementation should the compiler use? `Range<i32>`? Or my `Gobbledygook` type? Why? The compiler is not going to assume one way or the other.

So if you have `T: Trait<U>, U: Borrow<V>` or `T: Borrow<U>, U: Trait<V>` you'll always have to specify the intermediate type. Though if `Trait` used an associated type instead of a generic type parameter, then the intermediate type could be unambiguously deduced in the former case.

Comment: My example, using `RangeBounds`, was just an illustration of why one sometimes needs to accept "*anything I can borrows as the trait I actually need*", not a concrete requirement. As you say (and, as I pointed out in the conclusion of my question), the fiddling to work around the limitation in this case is trivial.

Comment: For this concrete example, however, I'm tempted to open a `rust-lang/rust` issue suggesting that `RangeBounds` is explicitly implemented in `core` for `&T` for all built-in `T` for which the decision was deliberately made *not* to implement `Copy`: `RangeFrom` etc. usw. … ... but I'm not so sure how well that will be received.

Comment: I've removed the section commenting on ranges and replaced it with one commenting on traits in general. Honestly, an `impl RangeBounds for &T where T: RangeBounds` doesn't sound that outlandish to me. Many other traits follow a similar pattern. Though I'm not sure if it'd be a breaking change.

Comment: I wonder about how it would be received because of the precedent it sets – should *every* trait in `core` be implemented for `&T`? If `RangeBounds`, where does it stop? Of course, I'd argue that `RangeBounds` is a suitable candidate because there was a deliberate decision to remove `Copy` from structs that otherwise would very obviously be `Copy` – removing `Copy` does rather break the priciple of least surprise rather glaringly.

Comment: What did you remove from the answer, btw? Stack's not showing me any differences...?

Comment: *"Stack's not showing me any differences"* - huh, either stack goofed up or I never actually saved my edit (probably the latter). I've edited it again to what I think I wanted to say before.

Comment: I think you shouldn't concern yourself with slippery slope arguments. Like I said, many other traits are implemented over references, so I don't think your suggestion would be precedential. Either way, those kind of concerns would be brought up by the library team if you do suggest it. I'm definitely not the one to weigh-in on that front.